# compile buildroot using external crosstool-ng toolchain (4.3.x)

Tags: compilation, linux-kernel, kernel, buildroot, crosstool-ng

I've built a toolchain for a power pc processor using `crosstool-NG`. `Crosstool-NG` automatically downloads the required sources from kernel.org to compile the toolchain.
Now I want to compile a `Linux` distro for the system and thought, using `buildroot` would be the easiest way to go about that. So I configured `buildroot` to use my existing cross toolchain but upon executing `make`, it complains:

```
>>> toolchain-external  Configuring
Incorrect selection of kernel headers: expected 2.6.x, got 4.3.x
```

is there anyway I can use buildroot with this toolchain at all or do I neec to wait until `buildroot` catches up with thir kernel version?

**EDIT1**
on selection of kernel hheaders 4.3.x, I got this error:

```
>>> toolchain-external  Configuring
Incorrect selection of gcc version: expected 4.3.x, got 5.2.0
```

and  the higest version number menuconfig lets me select is `4.8.x`

Comment: You didn't properly configure Buildroot for your exernal toolchain.  There's a config line *"External toolchain kernel headers series..."* where you are supposed to specify the version of the kernel headers that the toolchain is built with.  BTW you do not *"compile buildroot"*; you can *run* or *use* Buildroot.

Comment: @sawdust Hi, Yes Thank you for pointing that out, however, please see **EDIT 1** comment above. As for my misuse of *Buildroot*, yes you're entirely right - thanks for pointing it out, I've fixed this in the question now, too!

Comment: What version of Buildroot are you using?  The external gcc version specification  is not in older versions of Buildroot (e.g. v2015.05 and earlier).  But v2015.11.1 does offer choices up to gcc v5.x.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah,

Turns out I had to set the `toolchain gcc version` to `5.x` and the `toolchain kernel headers series` to `4.3.x`